# printing matrix (2-d) in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matrix, printing

I'm trying to print this code into a matrix but keep getting:

```
line 22, in <module>
    print(matrix[i][j], end=" ")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

## A basic code for matrix input from user

```
R = int(input("Enter the number of runners:"))
C = int(input("Enter the number of days to log:"))
names_runners = []
runners_time =[]

# Initialize matrix
matrix = []

# For user input
for i in range(R):  # A for loop for row entries
    a = []
    names_runners.append(input("enter name of runner" + str(i+1)))
    for j in range(C):  # A for loop for column entries
        runners_time.append(int(input("enter time for day" + str(j+1))))
    matrix.append(a)

# For printing the matrix
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(C):
        print(matrix[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: `matrix.append(a)`. You are appending an empty list(`a = []`). Perhaps you intended to append `runners_time` to matrix ??

Comment: Thanks Shiva. Worked brilliantly...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops out to me is that the number `R` is never initialized. I don't know if you maybe did this somewhere else in your code, but perhaps make sure that you have a valid value of R.

The second thing I'm noticing is that in the first outer for-loop, you create an empty list `a = []`... and then don't do anything with it. Make sure you're appending the actual data you care about into the matrix, because right now you're inserting it into unrelated lists and then appending an empty list. Hence, when you try to iterate over as many items as there are in your `names_runners` and `runners_times` lists, you end up going out-of-bounds.

Comment: `R` is initialized. It isn't visible due to formatting.

Comment: Alright, then the problem is probably the rest of my answer lmao

Comment: thanks, mppombo5...you are right about [a] being an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use dictionary in your case, here:

```
runners_dict = {}
runners_total = 2
days_to_log = int(input("Enter the number of days to log:"))

for i in range(runners_total):
    runner_name = input("enter name of runner" + str(i+1))
    runners_dict[runner_name] = []

    for j in range(days_to_log):
        todays_time = int(input("enter time for day" + str(j+1)))
        runners_dict[runner_name].append(todays_time)

print(runners_dict)
```

Results:

```
Enter the number of days to log:2
enter name of runner1joe
enter time for day1123
enter time for day2321
enter name of runner2bill
enter time for day1123
enter time for day2321
{'joe': [123, 321], 'bill': [123, 321]}
```

Comment: Thanks p0rc0_r0ss0. I think you're right about the dictionary, I will try it after I get this one to work. Thanks again...